# How can I limit bandwidth for a specific port/app in OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: macos, tcp

I am running OS X 10.10 Yosemite, and I am looking for a way to limit upload bandwidth specifically on TCP port 8333, so I can run Bitcoin Core to contribute outgoing bandwidth without completely saturating my connection.

Here is a list of utilities I have looked into:

- [ipfw](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html) - This has been deprecated since OS X 10.7, and has been removed in OSX 10.10. Unfortunately this also means that any ipfw GUIs are out too (Waterroof, Speedlimit, Noobproof, etc).
- [Network Link Conditioner](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) - This allows bandwidth limiting on Yosemite, but only on a system-wide level. I’m looking for a solution that will limit bandwidth only on a specific port, or only for a specific app, so my entire system won’t be affected by the limit.
- [pfctl](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/pfctl.8?query=pfctl&sec=8) - This is the new tool that replaces ipfw in Yosemite, but there is a lot less help available online, especially on limiting port/application bandwidth.
- [dnctl](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/dnctl/) - There is almost no documentation available for this online, but it seems like it may be able to do the job if configured properly. It has been mentioned before in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849499/how-could-bandwidth-be-throttled-limited-programmatically-in-yosemite), but the answer doesn't provide any examples on how to use/configure dnctl to limit bandwidth.

In short, I am looking for a way to limit bandwidth of a specific application/port on OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Does anything like this exist? And if so, how can I use it to limit outgoing traffic for a specific app, or on TCP port 8333?

---

Here is what I've tried with pfctl and dnctl:

```
Maximillians-MacBook:~ Max$ sudo pfctl -E
Password:
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Token : 1626248500898813477
Maximillians-MacBook:~ Max$ (cat /etc/pf.conf && echo "dummynet-anchor \"customRule\"" && echo "anchor \"customRule\"") | sudo pfctl -f -
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
Maximillians-MacBook:~ Max$ echo "dummynet in quick proto tcp from any to any port 8333 pipe 1" | sudo pfctl -a customRule -f -
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
Maximillians-MacBook:~ Max$ sudo dnctl pipe 1 config bw 10Kbit/s
Maximillians-MacBook:~ Max$
```

Unfortunately I'm still getting over 1Mbit/s chugging through my connection on port 8333.

Comment: Hi. Did this work for you? I tried a lot of options, read the manpages, looked here and there,  but could not throttle the bandwidth on a port (29719). I was able to create my anchor, and create pipes of smaller bandwidth, but somehow could not associate a port with the pipes.

Comment: @prasvin I haven't found a solution that's worked for me yet.

Comment: In my experience, dummynet works only when no port is specified. I.e. this works:  `echo "dummynet out on bridge100 proto tcp from any to any allow-opts pipe 4243" | sudo pfctl -a "customRule" -f -`  but this does not:  `echo "dummynet out on bridge100 proto tcp from any to any port 80 allow-opts pipe 4243" | sudo pfctl -a "customRule" -f -`

Answer (score 2):

For port 8333:

Create the anchor for pf to use:

```
(cat /etc/pf.conf && echo "dummynet-anchor \"customRule\"" && echo "anchor \"customRule\"") | sudo pfctl -f -
```

Create the PIPE to send the desired port to your dummynet anchor:

```
echo "dummynet in quick proto tcp from any to any port 8333 pipe 1" | sudo pfctl -a customRule -f -
```

Then set the desired speed for the pipe you created: (E.X: limit to 10mb/s)

```
sudo dnctl pipe 1 config bw 10Mbit/s
```

http://mop.koeln/blog/2015/06/01/Limiting-bandwidth-on-Mac-OS-X-yosemite/

I have been using a app called [Murus](http://www.murusfirewall.com), It claims to do this and much more but I have yet to get it to work on the free version for port throttling.  Very powerful otherwise of a gui app.

Comment: The help is much appreciated, but I was unable to get it to work. Please see my updated question.

Comment: It seems like this is limiting the incoming traffic, instead of the outgoing. To limit the outgoing traffic, change `dummynet in ...` to `dummynet out ...`.

Comment: I was able to create my anchor, and create pipes of smaller bandwidth, but somehow could not associate a port with the pipes. It would be helpful to know the output of `sudo dnctl list` after running these commands.